# Discord verification app wants permission to "initiate transactions'

Tags: wallets, nft

I'm new to metamask and just learning how to differentiate what is safe and what isn't. The discord verification bot wants to connect to my metamask. Specifically it is requesting to...

"See address, account balance, activity and initiate transactions."

The first three seem obvious but I'm not entirely sure what is contained within the fourth. I've googled around and have not found any comments on this particular language. The domain (collab.land) seems correct but I've read about lots of fake auth bots so I wanted to make sure.

Can someone describe for me what the 'initiate transactions' approval allows?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Someone asked a [similar question](https://www.reddit.com/r/Metamask/comments/spvpy3/initiate_transactionshavent_seen_that_information/) on reddit 4 days ago and a metamask team member replied, "Initiate just means propose them to you. This does not mean it will be able to perform transactions without your permission.", so it appears to be safe.